# OnAfterOpenProject called with fAdded == 1 when opening Solution in VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-extensions

I'm currently porting a VS2010 extension to VS2012 and I've seen that the `IVsSolutionEvents.OnAfterOpenProject(IVsHierarchy pHierarchy, int fAdded)` callback is called with `fAdded == 1` when I'm loading my solution. I believe this must be due to the asynchronous loading of the projects in VS2012. This doesn't happen with VS2010.

My question is then how can I know in `OnAfterOpenProject` that it's being called from the asynchronous project loading process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Although late to the party) From MSDN `IVsSolutionEvents.OnAfterOpenProject` reference [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivssolutionevents.onafteropenproject.aspx) that behaviour seems correct and the doc explains that (by now, at least):

> fAdded
>
> Type: System.Int32
>
> [in] **true** if the project is added to the solution after the solution is opened. **false** if the project is added to the solution while the solution is being opened.

And from your report, it seems that **false** (solution still loading) maps to **1**, so I guess **true** will map to **0**. This is somehow consistent with definitions in `VSConstants`:

```
public const int S_FALSE = 1;
public const int S_OK = 0;
```

Finally, in your `OnAfterOpenProject` implementation you can filter calls based on value of that `fAdded` input: if invoked with **1**, that means that the solution is still (asynchronously) loading, otherwise it means that a new project has been added to a (already loaded) solution.

Answer (score 1):

Please check out the following link from Microsoft VSX forum:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/br/vsx/thread/2d38f312-e566-4f65-bf2a-92041c51d7cc

Comment: It would be preferable to add here the main gist of the referenced document/page